# No sound as root and even with sudo su pi

Tags: audio, sudo

It works if I try to play a sound/mp3 with mpg321 as a pi user:

```
mpg321 Yeah-sound.mp3
```

but

```
sudo -u pi mpg321 Yeah-sound.mp3
```

does nothing and

```
sudo mpg321 Yeah-sound.mp3
```

leads to error

> Can't find a suitable libao driver. (Is device in use?)

I need to allow root user to play a sound or somewhat switch the user to play it. But interestingly this also does not work:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Music $ sudo su pi
pi@raspberrypi:~/Music $ mpg321 Yeah-sound.mp3
```

it leads to output similar to a case where the sound is played but nothing  really happened. It looks like the sound output is transmitted somewhere else. Any ideas?

I am using latest and pure install of Voice HAT for Raspberry Pi [downloaded from github](https://github.com/google/aiyprojects-raspbian/releases)

Comment: If you suspect that sound output is transmitted somewhere else, try defaulting it to the Audio Jack using `amixer cset numid=3 1` or to the HDMI using `amixer cset numid=3 2` Make sure to `sudo -i` before doing that, and when you're done, `exit` :)

Comment: @user96931 When I did that as user **Pi** (after `sudo su -l pi`) nothing change and there is no sound. If I did that as user **Root**, there is an error "amixer: Cannot find the given element from control default"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that leads to behaviour specific error related to OS version (Voice HAT on Raspberry Pi). Problem with sudo not playing music was resolved after installing pure "Raspbian Stretch Lite" and adding all necessary drivers.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you think you need `sudo` or what the commands you are trying to run actually do, BUT the issue is almost certainly related to your PATH.

Invoking `su` does not preserve the environment (see `man su`) so you loose access to some files accessible to `pi`.

The way you installed the programs can also affect access.

You can preserve your environment or use full paths on commands.

`sudo su -l pi …` will "Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly".

Comment: Unfortunately `sudo su -l pi` does not help. The problem remain the same. The output from the console looks like everything is fine but there is no sound. I checked the PATH and is the same after fresh log-in or after `sudo su -l pi`

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this issue, I could play music through Chromium but could not play sounds executed by root.

Make sure:

- The PI user and the ROOT user are using the same audio device (ROOT by default plays through HDMI (?))
- The volume for both users is 100% (e.g amixer sset Master,0 100%)
- Make sure to check your config at /etc/asound.conf